# IF Statement doesn't work correctly -> Comparing two tables and returning value

Tags: php, database, if-statement

I have the following problem: I want to compare two tables and see if in both is the same number. If in both is the same number, then I want to update the first table and return the value "He is in database", and if not then vice versa.

Here is what I do:

```
<?php

$DB_HostName = "localhost";
$DB_Name = "db";
$DB_User = "user";
$DB_Pass = "";
$DB_Table = "Relation";
$DB_Table2 = "Contacts";

$con = mysql_connect($DB_HostName,$DB_User,$DB_Pass) or die (mysql_error()); 
mysql_select_db($DB_Name,$con) or die(mysql_error()); 

$result = mysql_query("SELECT User FROM $DB_Table left join $DB_Table2 on User = Number", $con);

if ($result) {

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

echo "This user is already in database";
mysql_query("update $DB_Table2 SET Echo ='http://activity.24.eu/images /thumbsup.png'");        
}
else {
   echo "This user isn't in the database";
mysql_query("update $DB_Table2 SET Echo ='http://activity.24.eu/images/thumbsdown.png'");    
}
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

At the moment it always returns the first echo (even when it's not true) and therefore adding to every number the same value.

Comment: What value is mysql_num_rows returning when it should be returning 0?

Comment: It's always returning the first echo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a left outer join in your query, that means the result will contain all rows of table *Relation*, regardless if they have a corresponding row in *Contacts*.

The part `on User = Number` belongs to the join and describes which columns make the relation. If these are the attributes you meant to compare, you should put them into the WHERE part:

```
SELECT User FROM Relation left join Contacts on (Relation.field = Contacts.field) WHERE User = Number
```

Btw, you should take care, that all variables you put into an SQL string are properly escaped, to prevent SQL-Injections.

**Edit:**
According to the comments, i try to make an example:

If you want a list of all users with a corresponding Contacts.Number then write:

```
SELECT Relation.User FROM Relation INNER JOIN Contacts ON (Relation.User = Contacts.Number)
```

The result will be a list rows, each row containing one Relation.User value. Now you can loop through this rows and make a string like that 8,77,81,... .

To update your table you can write 2 updates like that:

```
UPDATE Contacts SET Echo = 'thumbsup' WHERE Contacts.Number IN (8,77,81);
UPDATE Contacts SET Echo = 'thumbsdown' WHERE Contacts.Number NOT IN (8,77,81);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your reply. I think I'm too new to php to get exactly what you mean. (Not the escaping part, but the one on Select and where). I do it like this $result = mysql_query("SELECT User FROM $DB_Table left join $DB_Table2 on WHERE User = Number", $con); But now it also gives back only the first echo "is in database" and updated them all to it.

Comment: Your problem lies in the SQL statement, not in PHP. If you could give me more information about your tables, i could write an example. I need to know what columns both tables have, which columns are used to make the relation between the tables, and which columns you want to compare.

Comment: To understand the left join, you could play around a bit on [SqlZoo](http://www.sqlzoo.net/select_left_join.htm).

Comment: I improved the example a bit, but since i do not know which field belongs to which table, i cannot make it clear.

Comment: Thank you, still the same outcome though. User is from Relation and Number is from Contacts. User in Relation is also just a number. This is why I want to check if the equal.

Comment: Maybe what you want is an `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`. I cannot tell, because i still don't know about the meaning of the fields. Do you want to know if for a given `Relation.User` a `Contacts.Number` with the same value exists?

Comment: Yes, exactly, that is what I want to know.

Comment: Added an example, note the `INNER JOIN`, hope i understood you correctly.

Comment: Thank you, I wanted to compare it with all users with a correspondning Number. So I used your second code, thanks. But sadly it still echoes for every user: "Is in Database", even though this isn't true. Only two of ten are actually in the first table. (Two user are in Table1 and ten in Table2, it still says that all the users who are in table2, are also in table1 :( )

Comment: Of course, have a look at the comment to this second example. You will get a list of all users with a corresponding Contacts.Number. Since you check if there are rows in the result, you will always get `true`. You can use this list of users, to make your UPDATE, there you can write `Update ... WHERE Relation.User in (8, 9, 10, ...)`.

Comment: Oh well. The first table has two columns and the second one has four. (to answer an earlier question). Is it possible to do it all at once? Or do I have to create the list first and use another php file?

Comment: Updated my example, it's even possible to write the statement in a single UPDATE query, but it would be hard to understand. I would recommend to read a tutorial about SQL queries.

Comment: Thanks again, I did that, still only given thumps up. I think I am doing something with the variables in the brackets wrong. Or aren' I supposed to change em?

Comment: Yes, you should change 8,77,81 to the result of your first query. For testing purposes, write some values by hand, you know are correct. Remove your if statement with `mysql_num_rows()` of course, this doesn't make sense.

Comment: I marked your answer as the correct one, thanks for staying with me that long. I removed the if with the rwos, but to be honest it still doesn't work. But I think with all your input I am going to find the solution. (But I have no idea how I get the result of my first query as numbers?!)

Comment: I'm confident, that you can solve this riddle. One last tip: solve one problem after the other, e.g. like that: 1) Play with the SQL-statements until you get what you want, phpMyAdmin is your friend. 2) Write some PHP code which does a static query and show the result on a page. 3) Execute a static update query with PHP. 4) Combine the PHP code and put variables in. Good luck!